# Does a person's internet connection affect the speed of sql queries or php parsing?

Tags: mysql

I started benchmarking with [Zend_Db_Profiler](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.profiler.html) by saving queries that take too long.  For one user, this query:

```
SELECT chapter, order, topic, id, name
FROM topics
WHERE id =  '1'
AND hidden =  'no'
```

took 2.97 seconds.  I performed an Explain:

```
select_type table  possible keys  key   key_len  ref    rows   Extra
SIMPLE      topics     id          id      4     const   42     Using Where
```

and ran the query myself from phpMyAdmin, and it only took 0.0108 seconds.  I thought that perhaps the size of the table might have an effect, as there is one column which is varchar and 8000 characters long, but it's not a part of the Select.  I also just switched over to semi-dedicated hosting but can't imagine that this would have had a negative effect.  Any thoughts as to how I could troubleshoot would be appreciated.

Comment: Please describe how exactly you do the benchmarking.

Comment: I use Zend_Db_Profiler (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.profiler.html), getting the time of each query as described on that webpage.

Comment: Mysql is not SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, your premise about bottleneck here is not right. Also, when testing how one query behaves within your browser and then within PHPMyAdmin (or any other GUI), you have to clear query cache before trying to do the same query again. You didn't mention whether you did that.

The second part of tracking what might be wrong includes confirming that your database's configuration variables have been optimally set, that you chose the proper storage engine, and that your indexing strategy is optimal (such as choosing an `INT` for primary key instead of `VARCHAR` and similar atrocities).

That means that in most cases you'd go with InnoDB storage engine. It's free, it's quick if optimized (server variable named `innodb_buffer_pool` does wonders when set to proper size and when you have sufficient RAM). Seeing you said that you use semi-dedicated hosting implies you don't have control over those configuration variables.

Only when you're sure that

1) **you're not testing the same query off of cache**
2) **that you've done everything within your power to make it optimal** (this includes making sure that you don't have rogue processes raping your server).

Only then you can assume there might be an error in communication between the server and client.

Comment: Though this answer leads me to more questions, it best answers my question as presented.  With a cleared query cache, and an INT for my indexing, I'm going to monitor the query over the next several days.  If it still appears to take a long time, I'll contact my hosting provider to see if there's anything that they see on their end.

Answer (score 3):

No. PHP and MySQL are server-side technologies, meaning your server processes them and has no bearing on the client. If your server is slow, it will just be slower in returning the response to the client.

Answer (score 2):

As both PHP and SQL run on a server side, the user's internet connection does not affect the speed of the query.
Maybe the database server was too loaded at the time and couldn't pass the query in time.

Comment: That was one possibility that I had thought of.  But, having just switched to a semi-dedicated server, I would have thought that this was less likely to happen.  If, however, the query runs fast when I do it within phpMyAdmin, does that mean that it has to be a server problem as opposed to being a query problem?

Comment: To make it clear, the web server with your php files is the same with your phpMyAdmin installation? Are they both connected to the same database server?
(Because if one of the answer is NO, then the results are not comparable.)

Comment: Yes, they're on the same server.